# Copy ONLY text from one range and paste ONLY the first three text on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have up to 6 cells with potential data coming from 6 different places. I am trying to get only the first three cells with data transferred to another sheet

```
Private Sub Transfer_Data()

Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).copy

Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This is what i have i know i am missing allot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
Sub Transfer_Data()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To 6
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If

    If j > 3 Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

EDITED:

```
Sub Transfer_Data()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    j = 3

    For i = 1 To 6
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
            j = j - 1
        End If

        If j = 0 Then Exit For
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks so much it works great. just wondering would it be possible to make the data go backwards on to sheet 2 meaning data first goes to cell A3 then A2 then A1??

Comment: @zgivod I just edited the post with a new solution, see above the comments.

Comment: the code works great thanks. just wondering how would i paste and keep the sheet 1 text color it changes to black when it gets pasted to sheet2

Comment: @zgivod If your question has changed please make a new post :). But what you need is `.Copy` and `.Paste` - but that's also going to require you activating the correct sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, there may be another, more elegant way of doing this:

```
Private Sub TransferData()

Dim cellCount as long

Dim cell as range
Dim rangeToCopy as range

For each cell in  Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' 23 is unnecessary, as you get all XlSpecialCellsValue constants by default
' See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells
cellCount = cellCount + cell.cells.count

If not (rangeToCopy is nothing) then
Set rangeToCopy = application.union(rangeToCopy, cell)
Else
Set rangeToCopy = cell
End if

If cellCount = 3 then exit for

Next cell

If not (rangeToCopy is nothing) then
rangeToCopy.copy

Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this already answered, but how about a crazy one-liner?

```
Sub TransferData()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A3").Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(Replace$(Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6").Value2), ","), ",,", ","), ","))
End Sub
```

Comment: the idea is cool but im getting error subscript out of range and theres too much code for me to debug...

Comment: Make sure `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` exist.